# undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass Agile Web Development with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, agile, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I'm trying to learn RoR from the book Agile Web Development with Rails and I get this error:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

    <ul>
        <% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
          <li><%= item.quantity %> &times; <%= item.product.title %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    app/views/carts/show.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_carts_show_html_erb___3275084074491266306_70111742218200'
    app/views/carts/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_carts_show_html_erb___3275084074491266306_70111742218200'
```

Here is Product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope :order => 'title'
    has_many :line_items
    before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
    validates :title, :description, :image_url, :presence => true
    validates :title, :uniqueness => true
    validates :price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01}
    validates :image_url, :format => {:with => %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)}i,:message => 'musí jít o adresu URL pro obrázek typu GIF, JPG, nebo PNG.'
    }
    private
    def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
      if line_items.empty?
        return true
      else
        errors.add(:base, 'Existují položky')
        return false
      end
    end
end
```

line_items_controller:

```
 def create
    @cart = current_cart
        product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

cart model:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity = current_item.quantity.to_i + 1
    else
     current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end
end
```

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0p247 and Rails 4.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Does your class LineItem have `belongs_to :product` ?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Yes it does > class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
  validates :product_id, presence: true
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may happen because cart item model do not save product_id.

1) First, add validation to LineItem model. It will not solve issue, but you will be sure that issue is related with product_id.

```
validates :product_id, presence: true
```

2a) Update controller to play with Rails 4 strong parameters:
http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

2b) Or use Rails 3 while learning Ruby On Rails.

UPDATE.

You should also remove previous LineItem records from DB using rails console, otherwise you will still see this error, because old LineItems not associated with Product.

Comment: can you please tell me how to remove the records?

Comment: @Nenor run rails console ("rails c") and destroy records ("LineItem.destroy_all")

Comment: I destroyed the records in database, rewrote the add_product to previous version and it is working now. Thank you very much! I'm really glad that Rails has such an amazing community. You were all very helpful. Now I will continue in learning, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

@gvalmon is right, but I would recommend to try using

`validates :product, presence: true`

And I'd change your code of add_product at least to this

`
  def add_product(product_id, qty = 1)

```
current_item = line_items.where(product_id: product_id).find_or_initialize
current_item.quantity += qty
current_item.save
current_item
```

end
`

P.S. dont forget to change qty default value to '0'

Comment: @gvalmon I added validates :product_id, presence: true but the error stays same. I don't have an idea how to deal with strong parameters so I will probably downgrade to Rails 3.

Comment: @Nenor, the problem is that you don't have product_id set (in DB)

Comment: I do have this migration class CreateLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :line_items do |t|
      t.integer :product_id
      t.integer :cart_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: I rewroted the code and this is what I get > undefined method `find_or_initialize' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_LineItem:0x007fd85f1011e0>

Extracted source (around line #5):
3
4
5
6
7
8
          

  def add_product(product_id, quantity = 1)
    current_item = line_items.where(product_id: product_id).find_or_initialize
    current_item.quantity += quantity
    current_item.save
    current_item

Comment: Ok, my mistake not find_or_initialize  but first_or_initialize .It is from rails 4. If it is not working then you should find needed method for your version of rails. Or can try

`line_items.where(product_id: product_id).first || line_items.where(product_id: product_id).create`